# Watin : - How to import csv file and test validation using watin?

Tags: csv, watin

I want to pass some text in my text field textbox and it should be passed from a CSV file which contains the multiple text.

But I find it much more difficult as I am not able to import the CSV file, so please help me with some example.

hope I made my question clear if not please let me know.

thanks,
regards,
Aman Khan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic loading of a CSV file and setting the Google search box to each value from the CSV file.  I found the csvParse method via a search for *C# read CSV*  http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/building-a-simple-csv-parser-in-csharp

Note that the google text box might not be the best for this example due to all the ajax-y calls.

Basic idea is read the CSV, returning a List of String arrays.   Iterate through the list and through the arrays, setting the textbox to each array value.

```
[Test]
public void CSVtest()
{
    IE myIE = new IE();
    myIE.GoTo("www.google.com");

    List<string[]> myCSVContents = parseCSV(@"C:\myCSVfile.csv");

    foreach (var currentCSVRow in myCSVContents)
    {
        foreach (var currentCSVvalue in currentCSVRow)
        {
            myIE.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText(currentCSVvalue);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
}

public List<string[]> parseCSV(string path)
{
    List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();

    using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string line;
        string[] row;

        while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            row = line.Split(',');
            parsedData.Add(row);
        }
    }

    return parsedData;
}
```

Using NUnit, WatiN2.1 and IE9 the code works like a champ.  Other than google out-search AJax-y calls.